# add Navigation Bar to Tap bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to have a common navigation bar to RecieptViewController and StockViewController and the bar should contain back button to go back to InventoryViewController.....
this code is written in InventoryViewController viewDidLoad:-

```
RecieptViewController *firstVC=[[RecieptViewController alloc]init];
UITabBarItem *itme1=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"First" image:nil tag:1];
itme1.title=@"Reciept";
[firstVC setTabBarItem:itme1];

StockViewController *secondView=[[StockViewController alloc]init];
UITabBarItem *item2=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Second" image:nil tag:2];
item2.title=@"Stock";
[secondView setTabBarItem:item2];

[tapBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVC,secondView,nil]];
```

Comment: explain better and understand question asking FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add navigation controllers to your `UITabBarController` then you must try the following:

```
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
UINavigationController *navigationController1, *navigationController2;

viewController1 = [[RecieptViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecieptViewController" bundle:nil];
viewController2 = [[StockViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StockViewController" bundle:nil];

navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

[tapBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray navigationController1,navigationController2,nil]];
```

Comment: If you want to add a `UIBarButtonItem` to navigation bar this code will help you to achieve this: `UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self 
                                                                  action:@selector(backPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;`

Comment: but still i m not able to see backButton on my navigation bar @Euroboy

Comment: Add this code in `viewDidLoad` method in your both view controllers.

Comment: i copied this code to both view controllers,now i can see the button but when i click the button it give error [RecieptViewController backPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.i have also written this method -(void)backPressed{
    NSLog(@"back");
} @Euroboy

Comment: Because you have not declared 'backPressed' method.
Add this code too:
`-(void)backPressed:(id)sender
{
    //do some stuff
}`